# Prove that if a polynomial f is constant for infinitely many arguments then it is constant.

Tags: polynomials

Let $f$ a polynomial with real coefficients. There exists a constant $ c $ such that $f(x)=c $ for infinitely many numbers $x$. Prove $f$ is constant.

I have no idea how to do this. I started by denoting $f=a_n x^n+...+a_0$ but I have no idea how to continue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let consider

$$p(x)=f(x)-c$$

and since $p(x)=0$ has at most $n$ solutions we have $p(x)=0 \implies f(x)=c$.

Comment: This is so cool. I never thought it is that easy! Thank you so much. I will remember this method for sure. I will accept your answer after the question reaches the 15 minute limit

Comment: @furfur You are welcome! Bye

Comment: This is so cool!

Comment: furfur.Have a look at Benjamin's proof in Martin R's comment.